# MVC: show Modal dialog from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can show modal dialog box within Controller.

for example:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int contractType )
        {
            if (contractType == 0 )
            {
                return "SHOW MODALDIALOG BOX" with button "YES" and "NO" when click "YES" Refirect to nexe page, click "NO" stay in current page
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

thanks for answers

Answer (score 4):

From Controller (Server) you can't show a popup.
What you CAN do is returning the view... with some flag to let the VIEW display a javascript modal dialog.

Other option is returning a JSON instead of a view... and create a modal dialog using JS.
Then... on clic YES, you can call the same Controller action with a different parameter (in your case something different that '0'), and this time show the View.

**Example:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registering( )
    {

        string RetResult =  new UserPermission().ValidateUser( Request["username"].ToString(), Request["password"].ToString() );

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RetResult)){
            ViewBag.MyErrorMessage = RetResult;
            return View(); //This will show the view named "Registering", but you can display any other.
//The ideal is display the same one where the user entered the user/pass.
        }
        else {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "EvalMain"); 
        }
    }
```

**In your VIEW:**

```
@if(ViewBag.MyErrorMessage != null){
     //Display the error message
     //You can: display it in a div (without popup), you can show a javascript Alert(), or display a modal dialog.    
}
```

**To display it as a DIV simply do:**

```
<div>@ViewBag.MyErrorMessage </div>
```

**To display an Alert():**

```
<script> alert(@ViewBag.MyErrorMessage);</script>
```

**To display a Modal Dialog**, you can use a jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
More or less something like this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Error Registering">
<p>@ViewBag.MyErrorMessage</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OK, but tell me a little more about the logic you are trying to accomplish... What is the idea of the modal dialog? What are you displaying in the View?

Comment: Thanks for answers. The idea is very sample. I have running eMemberShip WCF service, that accept ussername and password and return user role and permissions. If username or password not correct, service return Error string and than I want show ModalDialog with this error string and not redirect to other page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. The idea is very simple. I am running eMemberShip WCF service, that accept ussername and password and return user role and permissions.
If username or password not correct, service return Error string and than I want show ModalDialog with this error string and if not then redirect other page.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registering( )
    {

        string RetResult =  new UserPermission().ValidateUser( Request["username"].ToString(), Request["password"].ToString() );



        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RetResult))
            return this.ModalDialog(RetResult);

        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "EvalMain"); 
    }
```